# How to set file size to 100 Bytes in Windows in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-io

Could you please tell how to set file max size to 100 Bytes. If I try to write any more data more than 100 Bytes `ntwritefile()` should throw error `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.

Could you please suggest me, a widnows API to set 100 Bytes ( or a fixed size) to file ?

in our product, ntwritefile() fails with error ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY. I am trying to understand, in what are the scenarios, we will get that error.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you cannot get the system to limit the size of a file.

Comment: Why would windows provide such a thing? The size of the profile, sure, but the size of a single file?

Comment: Is there a reason you can not check this yourself in your code?

Comment: in our product, ntwritefile() fails with error ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY. I am trying to understand, in what are the scenarios, we will get that error

Answer (score 3):

Use `SetFilePointer`, then `SetEndOfFile`. Don't forget to `CloseHandle` after `SetEndOfFile`!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows this would look like this:

1. CreateFile
2. [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

That's it.

Comment: Yes, but this won't "fail" if more than 100 bytes are written (by this process or another).

Comment: On the prompt, you could also use "fsutil file createnew" (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx?mfr=true) to create a file with a fixed size.

Comment: as Joachim Pileborg said, this is up to you to set the size in your code.

Comment: just create a buffer of 100 bytes and set the parameter of WriteFile accordingly..

Comment: That wont result in an error being raised when the program attempts to write beyond byte 100, as was asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a buffer of size 100 char and write the buffer to a file when finished with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[100];

    //assign values
    memset(buffer, 'A', 100);
    buffer[5]='@';

    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ( "buffer.100" , "wb" );
    fwrite (buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer) , pFile );
    fclose (pFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to create a file of 100 bytes, he wants to ensure that he can't write any more than 100 bytes to it.

Comment: siva asked about setting a file to 100 Bytes ( or a fixed size), the above code can do that, not only in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a file that is 100 bytes? or do you want to limit the size of the file to 100 bytes meaning any further writes on the file will not work if the file exceeds 100 byte?

If its the first one you're after then you can use `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` and limit the buffer size to a 100 bytes.

If its the second one.. then I dont think its possible...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Serpent!. I am interested in second one

Comment: So is this file managed by your application or do you need the limitation on a global scale. I mean do u want the limit to be present even when writing to the file using a 3rd party text editor for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach, architecturally speaking, is as follows:

1. Identify how you're reading from and writing to the file in question.
2. Create an inteface that provides these same facilities via a single managed class. The API would be as near as possible the same to what you already have.
3. Add code, encapsulated in your manager class to track the size of the buffer as you write, probably also buffering the 100 bytes that you want in your file. Code can then detect and handle overflow situations in whatever way you deceide (i.e. throwing exceptions if that's what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you don't need a buffer for this.
Simply if you create a memory map object of file ,which is greater than the 
file size, the system automatically expand the file into that size.

But for just 100bytes you just create a 100 bytes of dummy char array and 
write it to the file.

see,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366542(v=vs.85).aspx